# Secure HTTPS transactions from HTTP client

Tags: security, rest, https

From the schema, is it possible to intercept the bearer token, the login and the md5 hashed password?

[image]

Do I have to use HTTPS also for the client to secure those transactions/exchanges with the REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends where your schema takes place. So if it happens in a VPN connection there is probably no need to further encrypt communication.

Assumed your Client access the Login page in the "standard" way, e.g. you later have a Login-Page which you want to be able to access with any webbrowser from any computer this is probably what you are looking for (to then dig into the details):

**The login/ password:**

If a client provides those information to a HTTP page instead of a HTTPS page it can be intercepted as cleartext if sent to that page no matter what you do with that data afterwards.

**The Token**

Above diagram indicates youre getting login credentials, make a md5 hash of the password and forward that information to a HTTPS secured page that gives you back a token (or not if the credentials were wrong).

The HTTPS secured system will however send the token back to you and you will send it to the client over HTTP so its cleartext interceptable as well.

**What you probably want:**

Is having the client establish a HTTPs secured connection to the login page, deliver HTTPs secured login credentials and if those are valid recives the token within the established HTTPs secured connection.

Comment: I updated my diagram to be more explicit. So the client HTTP send the credentials through a HTTPS REST API. In that case, is it secure?

Comment: Yeah in that case it is as secure as HTTPS itself.